# Retrieving UFID tag from audio file with ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, id3, ffprobe

## Context

I'm using `ffprobe` to retrieve metadata from audio files.
To do so, I usually use the following command:

```
ffprobe -hide_banner -v 0 -i audio.mp3 -show_entries format -of json
```

This gives the following result:

```
{
    "format": {
        "tags": {
            "title": "Try Me, I Know We Can Make It (edit)",
            "artist": "Donna Summer",
            "track": "3/9",
            "album": "Encore",
            "disc": "12/33",
            "TMED": "CD",
            "MusicBrainz Release Group Id": "c6b5e8d3-9ec1-4221-b595-857032b25249",
            "TORY": "2020",
            "MusicBrainz Release Track Id": "3c1c48bb-8f4f-4516-af8b-b5eadd99c469",
            "album_artist": "Donna Summer",
            "TSRC": "USIR20200908",
            "SCRIPT": "Latn",
            "TSO2": "Summer, Donna",
            "artist-sort": "Summer, Donna",
            "ASIN": "B083ZT9YFC",
            "originalyear": "2020",
            "publisher": "Driven by the Music",
            "TSST": "On the Radio (disc 1)",
            "ARTISTS": "Donna Summer",
            "BARCODE": "654378066023",
            "CATALOGNUMBER": "DBTMCDBOX02",
            "MusicBrainz Album Status": "official",
            "MusicBrainz Album Release Country": "XE",
            "MusicBrainz Album Type": "album/compilation",
            "Acoustid Id": "b2d70b30-8b7b-4207-bd9e-12c39419fb2b",
            "MusicBrainz Album Id": "0218662d-7e08-40f2-9b08-d41bace62e3b",
            "MusicBrainz Artist Id": "b60527cc-54f3-4bbe-a01b-dcf34c95ae14",
            "MusicBrainz Album Artist Id": "b60527cc-54f3-4bbe-a01b-dcf34c95ae14",
            "date": "2020-03-27"
        }
    }
}
```

However, in this result, I can't find the [UFID](https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#sec4.1) tag.
I know this tag is present in the file, because it is retrievable with `mutagen-inspect` more information [here](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/man/mutagen-inspect.html).
Using mutagen-inspect gives the following result:

```
APIC=cover front, Box (image/jpeg, 79556 bytes)
TALB=Encore
TDOR=2020
TDRC=2020-03-27
TIT2=Try Me, I Know We Can Make It (edit)
TMED=CD
TPE1=Donna Summer
TPE2=Donna Summer
TPOS=12/33
TPUB=Driven by the Music
TRCK=3/9
TSO2=Summer, Donna
TSOP=Summer, Donna
TSRC=USIR20200908
TSST=On the Radio (disc 1)
TXXX=ARTISTS=Donna Summer
TXXX=ASIN=B083ZT9YFC
TXXX=Acoustid Id=b2d70b30-8b7b-4207-bd9e-12c39419fb2b
TXXX=BARCODE=654378066023
TXXX=CATALOGNUMBER=DBTMCDBOX02
TXXX=MusicBrainz Album Artist Id=b60527cc-54f3-4bbe-a01b-dcf34c95ae14
TXXX=MusicBrainz Album Id=0218662d-7e08-40f2-9b08-d41bace62e3b
TXXX=MusicBrainz Album Release Country=XE
TXXX=MusicBrainz Album Status=official
TXXX=MusicBrainz Album Type=album/compilation
TXXX=MusicBrainz Artist Id=b60527cc-54f3-4bbe-a01b-dcf34c95ae14
TXXX=MusicBrainz Release Group Id=c6b5e8d3-9ec1-4221-b595-857032b25249
TXXX=MusicBrainz Release Track Id=3c1c48bb-8f4f-4516-af8b-b5eadd99c469
TXXX=SCRIPT=Latn
TXXX=originalyear=2020
UFID=http://musicbrainz.org=b'126cc184-b2a6-4743-803b-0953c85f7b0f'
```

For information, the files are written by [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org).

## Questions

- Is it possible to retrieve the UFID tag with ffprobe?
- If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Quick question. How did you manage to get the type of frames using `mutagen-inspect`?

I tried it and it just returns the tags without the type of frame each is.

Sample output below:

```
 mutagen-inspect 01-01\ The\ Funk\ Phenomena\ \(original\).flac


-- 01-01 The Funk Phenomena (original).flac
- FLAC, 417.20 seconds, 44100 Hz (audio/flac)
WWW=https://www.discogs.com/release/366804-Armand-Van-Helden-Funk-Phenomena-The-Album
STYLE=House
COUNTRY=Germany
GENRE=Electronic
DISCOGS_RELEASE_ID=366804
ARTISTSORT=Helden, van, Armand
MUSICBRAINZ_TRACKID=f4e7587e-35b3-4422-b23c-c79409d67e44
ASIN=B00008G9A5
ALBUMARTIST=Armand van Helden
ARTIST=Armand van Helden
MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMRELEASECOUNTRY=DE
MUSICBRAINZ_ARTISTID=b09b5127-c62e-4bb2-b790-1e4aa18749ed
CATALOGID=ZYX 20641-2
MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASEGROUPID=77b7408e-e6fb-31db-8c98-d998f94c4d79
MUSICBRAINZ_RELEASETRACKID=72763678-e460-39af-8716-c2c5611322a1
TITLE=The Funk Phenomena (original)
ALBUM=Funk Phenomena the Album
MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMID=24a15dd6-76a5-4ae8-a07a-8a0ed394c0f2
BARCODE=090204956487
ALBUMARTISTSORT=Helden, van, Armand
MEDIATYPE=CD
DISCNUMBER=1
MUSICBRAINZ_ALBUMARTISTID=b09b5127-c62e-4bb2-b790-1e4aa18749ed
DATE=2002
ORGANIZATION=ZYX Music
TRACKNUMBER=1/11
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Alex, I think you don't get the tag identifiers because you have no ID3v2 tags in your FLAC file. Try to do it on a mp3 file.